# How to remove the following characters in nginx rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to change this URL

http://example.com/xxxxx/yyyyyy%
to 
http://example.com/xxxxx/yyyyyy

from nginx rewrite rules. How?

Comment: Is that a percent-encoded percent character or just a badly formed URL?

Comment: Yes, it is just a badly formed URL

Comment: Try: `if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)%$) { return 301 $1; }`

Comment: It does not work